# How to insert a triple into a specific XML document?

Tags: marklogic

I noticed that while `rdf-insert` does not allow you to specify a document, only a graph.

Answer (score 3):

First, the key here is to recognize that there are two ways of storing and managing triples in MarkLogic.

1. managed triples - this is where you want to use MarkLogic as "just a triple store".
   You load triples using mlcp (the command-line bulk loader) or sem:rdf-load() or sem:rdf-insert(). 
   In this scenario, you don't want to know or care which documents the triples are stored in - you just want to load triples so you can query them later with SPARQL.
   That's why sem:rdf-insert() doesn't have an "insert it into this document" argument.
2. embedded triples - triples are embedded in an XML (or JSON) document.
   In this scenario, the triple is conceptually part of the document; so if you want to insert a triple into a document (embed a triple in a document) you should look to the *document* manipulation APIs rather than the *triples* manipulation APIs.

Once you have that mental model, you can choose to use sem:rdf-insert() if your triple is essentially "free-floating" - i.e. it doesn't matter which document it's in. Or you can choose to use something like xdmp:node-insert-child() if you really want to place that triple inside an existing document at some position.
(In MarkLogic 8 you can also use SPARQL Update to insert managed/free-floating triples.

That said, I wanted to see if I could do the node-insert-child in a simpler, more intuitive way - i.e. without the "trick" above.

First, it's good to build up the triple using sem:iri() and sem:triple() above - though you could build up the triple directly in XML. Using the sem: constructors is more robust.

Second, sem:triple() returns an object of type sem:triple, not an XML node. So you can't pass it in to xdmp:node-insert-child() directly.
But there *is* a helper function to translate from a sem:triple into an XML node - sem:rdf-serialize(), with a "triplexml" option.

So you can do this:

```
xdmp:document-insert( "/test/test.xml", <doc><title>test</title></doc>)
```

then:

```
import module namespace sem = "http://marklogic.com/semantics" 
      at "/MarkLogic/semantics.xqy";

xdmp:node-insert-child(
  fn:doc('/test/test.xml')/doc,
  sem:rdf-serialize(
      sem:triple(sem:iri("Firefly"), "is-a", "TV show"),
      "triplexml"
      )
)
```

... and you'll get:

```
fn:doc('/test/test.xml')
```

=>

```
<doc>
  <title>test</title>
  <sem:triples xmlns:sem="http://marklogic.com/semantics">
    <sem:triple>
      <sem:subject>Firefly</sem:subject>
      <sem:predicate datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">is-a</sem:predicate>
      <sem:object datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">TV show</sem:object>
    </sem:triple>
  </sem:triples>
</doc>
```

Answer (score 2):

Alex, you can insert a triple into a document using xdmp:node-insert-child(). There is one trick to it, which is that the function expects a node, and a triple isn't a node. This works:

```
xdmp:node-insert-child(
  fn:doc('has-a-triple.xml')/doc,
  <t>{sem:triple(sem:iri("Firefly"), "is-a", "TV show")}</t>/*
)
```

If you try it without the `<t/>/*` trick, you'll get an error:

```
xdmp:node-insert-child(
  fn:doc('has-a-triple.xml')/doc,
  sem:triple(sem:iri("Firefly"), "is-a", "TV show")
)
```

returns

```
XDMP-ARGTYPE: (err:XPTY0004) xdmp:node-insert-child(fn:doc("has-a-triple.xml")/doc, 
  sem:triple(sem:iri("Firefly"), "is-a", "TV show")) -- arg2 is not of type node()
```

Comment: Or `document { ... }/*` instead of `<t/>/*`. It's a little longer, but a little easier for me to type and read.

Answer (score 1):

While I don't think you can do that using rdf-insert, maybe it would be helpful for you to check out the embedded triples entry in the documentation:

From the [MarkLogic Semantics Developer's Guide](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/semantics/intro#id_32716)

> Triple documents with sem:triple as the document root are managed
>   triples in MarkLogic Server.
>
> You can also embed triples within XML documents and load them into
>   MarkLogic as-is.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <article>
>   <info>
>     <title>News for April 9, 2013</title>
>       <sem:triples xmlns:sem="http://marklogic.com/semantics>
>         <sem:subject>http://example.org/article</sem:subject>
>         <sem:predicate>http://example.org/mentions</sem:predicate>
>         <sem:object>http://example.org/London</sem:object>
>       </sem:triples>
>   </info>
> </article>
> ```
>
> The loaded triples are automatically indexed with a special-purpose
>   triple index. The triple index allows you to immediately search the
>   RDF data for which you have the required privileges.

So maybe you can try to insert a sem:triples node in the document and see if that gets indexed?

Comment: The sem:triples structure is incomplete, it is lacking a sem:triple that wraps each subject/predicate/object combination. It you adhere to that structure, you can put as many triples in any fragment, and they will get indexed if you have enable the triple index. You can even put them in properties.

Comment: Might be more future-proof though to use the sem:triple construction, or use something like `sem:rdf-serialize(sem:rdf-parse($rdf), "triplexml")`. Stephen Buxton gives a nice example..